# How to record MQ messages?

Tags: soapui, ibm-mq

I am trying to record all message traffic on some MQ server queues for using in a test suite. Are there any tools that can be used for this purpose?

I see that SoapUIPro and HermesJMS can be used for JMS testing, but can those be used for recording messages?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to record all message traffic on some MQ server queues for using in a test suite. Are there any tools that can be used for this purpose?

Do you want to record just the messages for your test or "any and all" messages that pass through a queue manager?  If it is the latter then there is a list of solutions [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html#mqtrk) that will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Capturing all messages is fine too.

Comment: Better Please put some opensource tool

Comment: There isn't any open source tools for capturing messages.  There some SupportPacs that will offload messages in a queue - you can find a list [here](https://capitalware.com/mq_tools.html).